# How to manage DNS for service that runs on both IPV4 and IPV6?

Tags: dns, ipv6

I have a web server that accepts IPv6 and IPv4 connections, and I would prefer that IPV6 be the default. However I am at a loss for how to *correctly* handle setting up the DNS for this.

Is the solution to simply make identical A and AAAA records for each domain/subdomain? I.E.:

x.mysite.com. 1800 IN A 192.xxx.xxx.xxx

x.mysite.com. 1800 IN AAAA 2604:xxxx:0:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx

Or should I be using SRV records? Something else?
I have googled and googled but cannot seem to figure out the answer to this, and it seems to be something that would be fairly common.

Comment: If you want your domain name to resolve to an IPv6 address, it is the same as an A record using the AAAA record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution is indeed to just provide an A and an AAAA record for the hostname. IPv6 is preferred by clients by default, usually with a Happy Eyeballs implementation. The client device chooses the protocol. You cannot influence that, only provide both addresses.